# Unable to type in textbox even with focus set

Tags: javascript

I have a flash keyboard (not written by me and I know no flash) which is used by the users to type in to the web forms. The keyboard works fine and I am able to fill the fields properly.

When the keyboard obscures any field, I am scrolling the document (in EnsureNotObscured() method) so that input field is not obscured. This is where I am getting the issue. After scrolling the document, I can see that the input field still has the focus (cursor blinks) but when I type nothing appears.

IF I click the mouse in that field again then I am able to type in that field. What could be the reason for this behavior? I even tried explicitly setting focus using 
document.getElementById(field.id).focus() after scrolling the document in EnsureNotObscured() and still it doesnt work. I even tried doing blur of the field and then setting focus back but no success.

Comment: What happens if you set focus on another field and then back to the original?

Comment: Is it not the same thing as blurring and setting the focus back on the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. I got it by blurring the field and setting the focus back after a timeout. I cannot write here why is it working because it involves our own javascript framework. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I know this is old news but I just wanted to say THANK YOU!!!  I've been working on a silly problem very similar to this and never once thought to first blur it and THEN focus it.  This worked for me!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Does this same behavior happen in all browsers?  I know I've had issues before with focus and scrolling with the mouse wheel in IE, but if I remember correctly this issue didn't happen in other browsers.

If it's just IE, I may be able to dig up some code I had to work around the issue.

Comment: Yes its IE. I havent even tested this in other browsers. Well I cant say why its only IE but it will be great if you can give some suggestions

Comment: So can you test this in other browsers, and let us know if the same problem occurs?

Comment: Well I cant, this app is running in our own proprietary env which runs IE. There are no other browsers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Horrible that an answer is even required here, but here's an IE8 safe way to make this lovely textbox issue go away:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets focus to a control using either the Page or ScriptManager method depending on which is available.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control"></param>
    public static void SetFocus(WebControl control)
    {
        string javaScript = String.Format("setTimeout(function() {{ $get('{0}').blur(); setTimeout(function () {{ $get('{0}').focus(); }}, 1); }}, 1);", control.ClientID);
        [ClientScript or ScriptManager].RegisterStartupScript(control, control.GetType(), "setFocus", javaScript, true);
    }
```

Happy coding.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Just need to take care of z-index property. Set a z-index in such a manner so that the text box should be at the top

Answer (score 0):

I'll help everyone with code of the answer given by user281693 -

```
jQuery(element).blur();
setTimeout((function(){
    jQuery(element).focus();
 }),100)
```

Where element is your text box.